# 'Error: expected a type' creating a new instance

Tags: c++, linux

I have a problem and I hope you can help me. 
I'm creating a C++ program which is running on linux.
I have defined two classes, where the main one is called Downloader and looks like this:

```
 #ifndef __DOWNLOADER_H__
 #define __DOWNLOADER_H__
 #include "configDownloader.h"
 #include "mailServer.h"
 #include <logger.h>

 using namespace ObjectModel;

 namespace Downloader
 {
     class Downloader
     {
        private:
                ...
                MailServer *m_mailServer;

        public:
                Downloader(char* configFileName);
                ...
     }; 
 }
 #endif
```

In the constructor of this class, I have tried to create a new instance of the class MailServer, which I defined into the same Namespace. The code of MailServer looks this way:

```
#ifndef __MAILSERVER_H__
#define __MAILSERVER_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <mail.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace ObjectModel;

namespace Downloader
{
    class MailServer
    {
        private:        
            list<Mail> m_mails;
            char *m_username;
            char *m_password;

        public:
            MailServer();
            ~MailServer();

            void Open(char *username,char *password);
            bool SaveEmails(char *pathFiles);
            void Close();
    }; 
}
#endif
```

The constructor of this class is defined correctly into the .cpp file and everything seems correct. 
The problem is that when I try to create a new instance of MailServer inside the constructor of Downloader, the compiler says **"error: expected a type"**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "downloader.h"
#include <unistd.h>

namespace Downloader
{
    Downloader::Downloader(char* fileName)
    {
        this->m_config = new ConfigDownloader(fileName);
        this->m_log = new Logger("Log",LOG_LEVEL_INFO,0);
        this->m_mailServer = new MailServer();//the compiler shows the error right here
    }
 ...
```

any ideas? I read somewhere that it could be that the compiler is too old, but I don't feel really comfortably coding inside the makefile.

Comment: what does the compiler tell you?

Comment: You may want to learn about `std::unique_ptr` and constructor initializer lists.  They won't fix the problem you're having, but they will help with others you haven't even spotted yet.

Comment: Also, `using namespace std;` in headers is bad style.

Comment: thanks! I will consider that! :)

Comment: Also, is that the *first* error generated by the compiler?  Sometimes the editor will lie and show them out of order in its "issues" or "errors and warnings" pane, look at the actual compile log.

Comment: Is "mailServer.h" correct in the `#include` in the `Downloader` header? Is it perhaps "MailServer.h" with a capital 'M'?

Comment: in fact, is the first one as you said... it has some warning but nothing relevant. I don't know what could be... as i said before the constructor of MailServer, is defined into the .cpp as an empty function, so i think there is not the problem. I don't know what else can be important to say :S

Comment: No charlie... i called mailServer.h the file, and MailServer the class. I used this nomenclature in the whole solution

Comment: There's not much point introducing namespaces if you're going `using namespace ...` all over the code, especially in headers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I'm sorry because i didn't see it. The problem was that i defined a public getter to return the private field like this:

```
class Downloader
{
    private:
        ConfigDownloader* m_config;
        Logger* m_log;
        MailServer *m_mailServer;

    public:
        MailServer *MailServer();
```

being that both was define into the same scope, the compiler could be confused about the constructor of the class and the method, because both were called with the same name. The problem was mine! But everyone should take care about this, because intellisense doesn't tells you anything about it